# Double clicking on an item in a listbox in tkinter and having that item show in search bar

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my first time posting here so bare with me! I'm building an app that has a listbox of football player. What I'm trying to figure out is, I want to double click on an item in the `listbox` and I want it to show up in the search entry when clicked.

Here is my code. I've tried binding the button click and creating a new function to try and view the selected item in the search box. I've watched a few videos of trying to figure it out but they all do it without OOP, so maybe I'm putting these `keybinds` or functions in the wrong place. I just want to be able to double click an item in my `listbox` and have that name appear in the search bar.

```
import re
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = tk.Tk()


class Player:
    """Creating the information for the soccer player"""
    def __init__(self,name,team,number):
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.number = number




class Screen:

    def __init__(self,master):
        # Creating the main tkinter window
        self.master = master
        self.search_player()

    def search_player(self):
        """The main search window, this is where you will search for the player"""

        string1 = tk.StringVar()

        # Clears first frame
        for i in self.master.winfo_children():
            i.destroy()
        # Create first frame
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.master, width=500, height=300)
        self.frame1.pack()
        # Search Label
        self.search_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Search Player:", font=("Times, 12"))
        self.search_label.place(x=15, y=50)


        # Entry for searching
        self.search_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, font=("arial, 15"),textvariable=string1)
        self.search_entry.place(x=125, y=50)
        # Search Button
        self.search_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Search", font=("Times, 13"), command=lambda: self.player_info_screen())
        self.search_button.place(x=360, y=47)

        # Listbox storing players name
        self.listbox1 = tk.Listbox(self.master,font=("Times, 12"))
        self.listbox1.place(x=125, y=100)

        # Scroll bar for list box
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.master)
        self.scrollbar.place(x=310, y=100)

        # Attaching listbox to scrollbar and scrollbar to listbox
        self.listbox1.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.listbox1.yview())

        # list made up of each object instance showing players name
        footballer_names = [player1.name, player2.name, player3.name, player4.name]
        # Adding players into listbox
        for name in footballer_names:
            self.listbox1.insert(0, name)



player1 = Player("Neymar","Paris Saint Germain","10")


player2 = Player("Lionel Messi","Inter Miami","30")


player3 = Player("Kevin De Bruyne","Manchester City","17")

player4 = Player("Cristiano Ronaldo", "Al Nassr", "7")


window = Screen(root)



root.geometry("500x400")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to double click on an item in the listbox and I want it to show
> up in the search entry when clicked.

The problem can be fixed.

- add `self` to `self.string1`
- Create function called `print_selection`.
- Add `self.listbox1.bind` after `self.listbox1.place`

Code:

```
def search_player(self):
    """The main search window, this is where you will search for the player"""

    self.string1 = tk.StringVar()
    :
    :     
    
 
    self.listbox1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.print_selection)
 

    # Attaching listbox to scrollbar and scrollbar to listbox
    self.listbox1.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.scrollbar.config(command=self.listbox1.yview())

    :
    :          
 
def print_selection(self, event):
    value = self.listbox1.get(self.listbox1.curselection())   
    self.string1.set(value)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

You can set your text flag on the labels/ search field to return a function instead of a default string, so you can create a function that returns "Search Player" by default and then changes the return value to whatever player name it is when that player is double clicked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).